# Eclipse plugin to align the equals signs on multiple lines

Tags: python, eclipse

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that will align the equals signs on multiple lines and align words on multiple lines in columns.

Example:

```
def __init__(self, dim, ngram, hdim, nwords):
    self.dim = dim
    self.ncond = ngram - 1
    self.hdim = hdim
    self.nwords = nwords
```

should become:

```
def __init__(self, dim, ngram, hdim, nwords):
    self.dim    = dim
    self.ncond  = ngram - 1
    self.hdim   = hdim 
    self.nwords = nwords
```

Bonus point if it can also handle comments, i.e.

```
def __init__(self, dim, ngram, hdim, nwords):
    self.dim = dim  # word vector dimension
    self.ncond = ngram - 1  # number of conditioning words
    self.hdim = hdim  # number of hidden layer units
    self.nwords = nwords  # vocab size
```

should become

```
def __init__(self, dim, ngram, hdim, nwords):
    self.dim    = dim       # word vector dimension
    self.ncond  = ngram - 1 # number of conditioning words
    self.hdim   = hdim      # number of hidden layer units
    self.nwords = nwords    # vocab size
```

[OCDFormat](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/) is pretty good but [has an issue with some (common) operators](https://github.com/eduardp/OCDFormat/issues/5), so I am looking for alternatives.

On Sublime I use the [Sublime Alignment](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) pluging (free):

[image]

[image]

On Notepad++ I use [Code-Alignment](http://codealignment.com/) (use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20481399/395857).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Eclipse plugin [columns4eclipse](http://columns4eclipse.sourceforge.net/):

- gratis
- open source
- I've tested it with Eclipse 4.3 x64 and 4.5 x64 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

[image]